# how to Make only one column editable in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I want to make my `JTable` unEditable but i want to add `JButton` to to it and the column of the button must be editable for the press event so how can i make this only column editable?

here is my table model code:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{ 
                                        "IDemp",
                                        "empNumber",
                                        "Fname","Lname",
                                        "BirthDate",
                                        "Address",
                                        "email",
                                        "Button" }
                                       );
//TableCellRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();

for(int i=0;i<emps1.size();i++) {
    model.addRow(new Object[]{String.format("%d",emps1.get(i).getIDemp()),
                                String.format("%d",emps1.get(i).getEmpNumber()),emps1.get(i).getFname(),
                                    emps1.get(i).getLname(),emps1.get(i).getBirthDate(),
                                        emps1.get(i).getAddress(), emps1.get(i).getEmail().getEmailAddress()});
}
```

and here is my jtable:

```
JTable emps=new JTable(model);
emps.getColumn("Button").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
emps.getColumn("Button").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
```

How could I make the "Button" column editable and the others not?
*And if you have better way to add `JButton` to the `JTable` it will be great."

Comment: Create something like `MyTableModel` which extends `AbstractTableModel` and override the function `isCellEditable(int row, int column)`. Simply check `if (column == desiredColumn) return true; else return false;`. I guess that will do :-)

Comment: you don't need to use AbstractTableModel only to override isCellEditable, nothing else

Comment: yea but when I'm doing it i losing the option to this: model.setColumnIdentifiers() and model.addRow()

Comment: why is there ButtonRenderer for JCheckBox, put Boolean value in to DefaultTableModel, overide getColumnClass, more in offcial Oracle tutorial, bunch of Q&A here

Comment: ok tnx it worked! :))

Comment: @mKorbel: If I am not mistaken, isn't `DefaultTableModel` use to consider every input as a `String` value? Or can we modify it too, to make it work like an `AbstractTableModel`?

Comment: @nIcE cOw AbstractTableModel is way to 1. use arrays (util.List etc) which aren't implemented in API (new Object[], Vector), 2. to restrict/enhace (by override) methods implemented (allowed by default) in DefaultTableModel, if isn't overrode (in AbstractTableModel) then is restricted by default (nice to see you here again)

Comment: @mKorbel: Thankyou, seems like I need to learn `JTable` a bit more. Still reading it each day to get something new out of it. This knowledge provided by you, will be helpful in the process as always :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extends the `AbstractTableModel` and override `isCellEditable` like this:

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

     public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (col== columnIndex) { //columnIndex: the column you want to make it editable
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yea i found it but were i add the rows to the model like i did?

Comment: @DorCohen you just need to create an instance of your own table model instead of `DefaultTableModel`.